# Haskell - how do I strip trailing spaces

Tags: haskell

I want to convert [1,2,3] to "1 2 3". at the moment I get "1 2 3 ".
I import strip function using

```
import Data.Text (strip)
```

My code look like this:

```
ar2str ar = (concatMap (\x -> (show x)++" " ) ar)
```

How do I modify ar2str so that it works with strip?

### Found it

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_whitespace_from_a_string/Top_and_tail#Haskell

Rosetta Code to the rescue :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use `Data.Text.unwords` instead of all that. Or, if you're using `String` instead of `Text`, `Data.List.unwords`.

Comment: Surely you mean `unwords`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, yes, indeed, or possibly `intercalate`.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping trailing space makes sense if one processes given input strings.  If one produces strings, its better just not to append the space in the first place.  Especially that given the nature of Haskell lists, removing element from the end equals rebuilding the list.

Here's one way to achieve desired effect:

```
ar2str :: Show a => String -> [a] -> String
ar2str _ [x] = show x
ar2str sep (x:x':xs) = show x ++ sep ++ ar2str sep (x':xs)
```